# Numerical matrix inverse vs. analytical matrix inverse using numerical inputs

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

From what I've read, it seems that explicit numerical matrix inversion is considered a bad idea. However, what if we have an invertible matrix $A$, and find the analytical expression for $A$'s inverse, and then put our numerical values into the analytical expression we just found? Would we be able to attain more stable/accurate results than simply using inv($A$) or would the two simply be exactly equivalent?

Comment: You should normally avoid computing the inverse in almost all cases. Why do you need it? (Solving a linear equation can be done better without matrix inversion!) It you **really** need it, and there **are** analytical expressions for the coefficients, which can be computed with a **stable** algorithm, then use it. If in doubt, consult a textbook like Higham, Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms.

Comment: Could you explain your statement that "solving a linear equation can be done better without matrix inversion" a little further, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: See **Higham, Ch.14.1 'Use and Abuse of the Matrix Inverse'**. To paraphrase here:
For a $n\times n$ matrix  $A$ solving $Ax=b$ using $A^{-1}$ requires $2n^3$ operations, where as Gaussian elimination needs $\frac{2}{3}n^3$, i.e. it three times more expensive than Gaussian elimination with $\frac{2}{3}n^3$  operations. 
And Gaussian elimination is usually much  more stable than computing $A^{-1} b$, even if $A^{-1}$ is formed exactly.

Comment: @gammatester , I am not convinced by your last sentence. If you use LU method for the calculation of $A^{-1}$, then  solving $LUx=b$ gives the same result as the calculation of $A^{-1}b$. For example, if $n=100$, $A$ is the Hilbert matrix, $b$ is a random vector and if we calculate with 200 digits,  then, in both calculations, we lose 150 significative digits (according to the value of $cond(A)$).

Comment: Note: It is not my statement, but a paraphrase of Higham. The exact citation is (second paragraph in 14.1): *Not only is the inversion approach three times more expensive, but it is much less stable. Suppose $X = A^{-l}$ is formed exactly, and that the only rounding errors are in forming $x = fl(Xb) \dots$*